# Closures and multiple instances

Tags: javascript

I like closures because you can make an API from them but it sucks that you can't have multiple instances.

http://jsfiddle.net/LxCJe/1/

```
var Person = (function () {

    // private properties and methods
    var Constr, name;

    // public API
    Constr = function (n) {
        name = n;
    };

    Constr.prototype.sayName = function(){return name;};

    return Constr;
}());


var person1 = new Person('Foo');
var person2 = new Person('Bar'); //New values will overwrite the name because of the closure.

console.log(person1.sayName()); //Bar
console.log(person2.sayName()); //Bar
```

**Is there an alternative way to be able to use prototypes to access private members and create different instances?**

Comment: They are private but not unique to each instance. Don't worry about encapsulation in JS, it's fine to do `this._name`, so the underscore is a convention that means "private".

Comment: Prototyped methods are shared, so they can't access variables on a per-object basis. @elclanrs: Solution should be more than sufficient in most cases. Otherwise, you're going to forgo the prototyped methods, and give each instance its own method.

Comment: @cookiemonster—but public methods can access private members via privileged methods, so it's not the end of the world, just a little more inefficient. :-)

Comment: @RobG: By "public" are you talking specifically about prototyped methods? If so, yes, that's true, but I wouldn't see the point of it since you'd still need to create methods on a per-instance basis. So why have the prototyped methods call the per-instance methods instead of just calling the per-instance ones directly?

Comment: @cookiemonster—"but I wouldn't see the point of it" indeed, which is why most who head down this road end up just "going public". :-) Privileged methods can emulate getters and setters, but again, the properties they modifiy might just as well be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to make use of constructor and the members as private, then you can do like this

```
var Person = function(my_name) {

    // private properties and methods
    var Constr, name;

    // public API
    Constr = function(n) {
        name = n;
    };

    Constr.prototype.sayName = function() {
        return name;
    };

    return new Constr(my_name);
};
```

**Note:**

1. But this is not efficient, as we have to create `Constr` constructor everytime you create an object of `Person`.
2. It makes inheriting from `Constr`/`Person` impossible, as `Constr` cannot be accessed from outside and the prototype of `Person` is empty.

   ```
   console.log(Person.prototype); // {}
   ```

I would think that, not all the variables would be private in your class. So, you can have private members, like this

```
var Person = function(my_name) {

    // private properties and methods
    var name = my_name;

    // public API
    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    }

    this.setName = function(newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
};

Person.prototype.printName = function() {
    console.log(this.getName());
}

var person1 = new Person('Foo');
var person2 = new Person('Bar');

console.log(person1.getName()); // Foo
console.log(person2.getName()); // Bar
console.log(Person.prototype);  // { printName: [Function] }
person1.printName();
person2.printName();
```

Comment: Yes, it's common to use privileged methods to get and set values of private members (and maybe other stuff) so they are available to inherited methods. But as elclanrs said, sometimes in the end it's not worth the effort as long as you are disciplined (not always the case in a team though).

Comment: Knowing the latter, there seems to be no other way. Thanks for showing the unorthodox option as well though!

Answer (score 1):

I think the way of the future is [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), which has compatibility with browsers that are generally HTML5 compatible (IE9+, most notably; see [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) for the best backfilling you can do).

With that, you could define read-only getters that look like attributes (not functions), and don't foul up prototypal inheritance or create a new constructor function every time: ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ycxQ3/))

```
// name is read-only, but only modern browsers (ie 9+)
function Person(attributes) {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        name: {value: attributes.name}
    })
}

person1 = new Person({name: 'Foo'});
person2 = new Person({name: 'Bar'});

console.log(person1.name) // Foo
console.log(person2.name) // Bar
```

Alternately, similar to what someone else commented, you could do the following for better browser compatibility while maintaining prototypal correctness and a read-only API:

```
// read-only-ish, but better browser compatibility
function Person(attributes) {
    this._name = attributes.name
}
Person.prototype.name = function() { return this._name }

person1 = new Person({name: 'Foo'});
person2 = new Person({name: 'Bar'});

console.log(person1.name()) // Foo
console.log(person2.name()) // Bar
```

Comment: That's awesome. How would you access/overwrite name using `Object.defineProperties` inside Person?

Comment: @Tek Depends on your intent. You could call Object.defineProperties again (haven't tried, just makes sense), or better yet if you just want a standard getter/setter you can add `writable: true` to `{value: attributes.name}`

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of constructors here and create a new public interface each time `new Person(name)` is called:

```
function Person(name)
{
    // return public api that closes over 'name'
    return {
        sayName: function() {
            return name;
        }
    };
}
```

The public interface that you return will no longer be an instance of `Person`, that's something to keep in mind about this particular approach.